# Python Plot related warning

Tags: python

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "D:\python\line graph for Compressive Strength.py", line 22
    plt.plot( 'x','y', data=df1, linestyle='-', marker='o',label='AR1154', color='#7f6d5f')
RuntimeWarning: Second argument 'y' is ambiguous: could be a format string but is in 'data'; using as data.  If it was intended as data, set the format string to an empty string to suppress this warning.  If it was intended as a format string, explicitly pass the x-values as well.  Alternatively, rename the entry in 'data'.
```

How to solve the warning given above?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your df1 contains columns named 'x' and 'y'. In a sense, the warning objects to you using 'x' and 'y' for column names in your DataFrame.  When you passed 'y' as a column name, it thought that maybe you were saying 'y' for yellow, and you wanted a yellow line.

So one solution would be to rename your y column in the data frame to 'y_axis'.

There is an optional 3rd argument to plot -- a format string. Changing your call to this should fix it:

```
plt.plot('x','y', '', data=df1, linestyle='-', marker='o',label='AR1154', color='#7f6d5f')
```

This happens because the [arguments to plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) are defined in a way that makes it impossible to tell whether some arguments are column names or are a format string. I just always throw in a 3rd argument of '' to remove the ambiguity.